# udisks - automatic mounting partitions at startup

Tags: mount, fstab, udisks

Update:

I posted an answer following @sourcejedi's tip!

---

I installed OpenMandriva Lx 3.0 and Rosa Linux R10 on the same PC. And I noticed that unlike previous systems (I used Mageia 5, Rosa R9), which partitions mounted through `fstab`, they use only `udisks`.

But in OpenMandriva, all the partitions automatic mounted at startup, while in Rosa, I must mount it manually (e.g., click on the partition icons on side bar 'Place' of Dolphin).

Also, if I add another HDD (not hot-plugged), OpenMandriva also automatic mounts all new partitions (at boot) without edit anything, it's convenient compare to `fstab` method.

I try to adapt this config to Rosa, but don't know where to find?

Answer (score 1):

I searched for the wrong direction.

It belongs to KDE configuration: System Settings > Removable Storage > Removable Devices > Enable automatic mounting of removable media